# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 1561881140820'. Current value: 'null: 1561881140880'

Tags: angular

In my app, there is a getter that returns new date everytime and I want to update the style of an element based on that date.
Here is the simple example:

app.component.html

```
<h1>Gantt-Flexx</h1>
{{currentMillis}}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent{
    get currentMillis(){
        return new Date().getTime()
    }
}
```

This trigger this error

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 1561881140820'. Current value: 'null: 1561881140880'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:17871)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:17859)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:18059)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:27635)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:27624)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:28228)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:28182)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AppComponent.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:28171)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:27525)
```

Comment: Try adding `{{currentMillis | async}}` - `async` pipe

Comment: InvalidPipeArgument: '1561881667718' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Try to add `get currentMillis(){
        return new Date().getTime()
    }` this inside **'ngAfterViewInit'** life cycle hook

Comment: @TSR : In case you want to handle your scenario, can u elaborate more about component behavior, so that I can suggest better approach in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are assigning `currentMillis` to angular expression using `{{currentMillis}}` , so this function `get currentMillis()` is triggered on every change detection cycle.

Try putting `console.log` in that function and see (*Make sure you are never assigning  a function to `{{ }}` because it would be called unnecessarily and impact the performance*). So, every time Change detection runs, it gets different value because the `time` is changed every millisecond.

Refer [ChangeDetection video](https://youtu.be/DsBy9O0c6eo?t=441) to handle this exact problem and why it happening

Comment: It would be better if you provide a solution with proper CD handling technique (*or to handle this type of scenario's*)!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Good point, I have asked to provide me exact expected behavior so that I can provide him some better approach

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error also, 
the solution I did was simply another way to get the time:
In your html:

```
<h1>Gantt-Flexx</h1>
{{currentMillis}}
```

and in your ts, instead of the getter:

```
export class AppComponent{
  currentMillis:Date;

  constructor(){
    this.utcTime();
  }

   utcTime(): void {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.currDateTime = new Date();
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Hope this helped you. Of course, the  value in the `setInterval` function you can change as you like.