# Angular, when can I use template references variables within angular directives?

Tags: angular

I'm new in angular and I have this doubt. I have a very strange behaviour using the next code:

```html
<select #selectColor class="btn btn-primary" name="button">
  <option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of COLORS">{{color}}</option>
</select>

<p customDirective [ngStyle]="{'color':selectColor.value}">
  Test paragraph
</p>
```

This code shows the next error in browser console and it doesn't work:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'color: '. Current value:
>   'color: yellow'.

But it "works" and change the color when I pass mouse over the element because the customDirective has defined the next methods:

```
@HostListener('mouseenter') mouseEnter(){
    //Some code
}

@HostListener('mouseleave') mouseLeave(){
    //Some code
}
```

I upload a demo at:
https://angular-zxhhml.stackblitz.io

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823298/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-previous-value-null-156188114082/56823384#56823384 /. It has useful references on whats happening under the hood for this error. In your case, can show the directive code , then i point out the exact reason. Best option would be to provide a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/ . I'll provide answer quickly then

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Here is the demo: https://angular-zxhhml.stackblitz.io

Comment: Sure, will take a look. Give me sometime. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the value of a template variable to a directive. You do not want to use property binding.

You can force the bound template variable to update by adding a `(change)` event handler with some arbitrary expression.

**component.html**

```html
<select class="btn btn-primary" name="button" #selectColor (change)="0">
  <option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of COLORS">{{color}}</option>
</select>

<p customDirective [ngStyle]="{'color':selectedColor}">
  Test paragraph
</p>
```

Of course, the more standard (in my opinion) - and easier - way to do this is with property binding.

`[(ngModel)]="selectedColor"`, and then bind to `selectedColor`. No property is strictly required in the component, although I would always recommend adding one for clarity.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lz1cae

Comment: Thanks, I know I can use [(ngModel)] but I'm trying avoiding add another variable in the component.

Comment: Why? The component gives you a sense of what's happening without having to scan through the html. My defining some kind of API you are creating some sort of self-documenting code.

Comment: Also, you don't *have* to declare the property in the component. We are ultimately writing Javascript. *Any* property can be added to the component at runtime.

Comment: Because I want a deep knowledge of framework and  I want avoid add a variable to component that only is used as style variable and it doesn't save any information.

Comment: You can still use `[(ngModel)]` without declaring a variable on the component. Component properties aren't just for "saving" data - it's a nice standard way for most Angular developers to pass data around - even if it is transient.

Comment: If your question is more about exploring alternatives to the standard way of doing things, then I would recommend editing your question to make it more specific.

Comment: For what it's worth, handling the `(change)` event with some arbitrary expression is one way of "updating" the value. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lz1cae It could be a clue in your research.

Answer (score 0):

On Component/Directive creation, Angular executes a set of methods that's is known as the lifecycle hook. This mechanism is described here :

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

The problem is that all methods of this lifecycle are executed on the same javascript vm turn and when your select is created the first value (here yellow) will be selected, and causes that error.

A solution, as said in previous answer is to use ngModel to keep track of the color that is selected. In order to select the first color by default, I use the setTimeout function that allow to postpone execution on next javascript vm turn and avoid the previous error.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  COLORS = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue'];
  selectedColor: string;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedColor = this.COLORS[0];
    });    
  }
}
```

Then link selected color to your directive using an Input.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customDirective]'
})
export class CustomDirectiveDirective {

  @Input() color: string;

  constructor(private readonly element: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseEnter(){
    // Some code
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseLeave(){
    // Some code
  }

}
```

Here is an example on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssq5af